# How can I hide this low voltage wire for my Nest thermostat?

Tags: electrical, wiring, thermostat

Our HVAC is too old for a C-wire or C-wire adapter. I installed this to keep power to the thermostat. Would it be up to code if I put a recessed wall outlet in and then ran the wire behind the wall into the thermostat? We hate the look of the wire on the outside like this.

Any other ideas I’m open to. We just want a clean look with no external wires or coverups.

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Since the wire from the transformer/wall wart to the Nest is low voltage, you could poke a hole through the wall and run just that wire behind the drywall.

Comment: How is your HVAC "too old" for a C-wire or adapter? Can you post photos of its wiring diagram please?

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole Code book of rules regarding line voltage hardware. In the case of what you're proposing, the answer is 'probably yes'.

That is: installing a recessed wall outlet is fine. They make such things, typically for going behind a TV that is flush mounted. Follow the manufacturer instructions and you will be good to go with such a change.

It's also OK to run the low voltage wire behind the wall. Low voltage wire rules are very flexible. Rules for running line voltage are much stricter (as in the above mentioned Code).

However there's one more option here: a device called a 'common maker' can use your existing thermostat wires to effectively add an Common wire. It will require a 24VAC transformer at the furnace end, but in the unlikely event that your furnace is missing a transformer, it's easy to add one there without worrying about how it looks on your wall. If you don't want to / can't easily run new thermostat wiring, take a peek at this sort of device.